# why does this it say in the console Process finished with exit code 0 instead of printing the 'sen' variable?

Tags: python, python-3.8

```
import random
import sys


def v1_debug(v1, subject):
    if v1 != str and subject != str:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        if subject == 'He' or 'She' or 'It':
            for i in v1:
                if i == [len(v1)+1]:
                    if i == 's' or 'z' or 'x' or 'o':
                        v1 = v1 + 'es'
                    elif i == 'y':
                        v1 = v1 - 'y' + 'ies'
                elif v1[len(v1)] == 's' and v1[len(v1)+1] == 'h':
                    v1 = v1 + 'es'
                elif v1[len(v1)] == 'c' and v1[len(v1)+1] == 'h':
                    v1 = v1 + 'es'
        if subject == 'I' or 'You' or 'We' or 'They':
            for i in v1:
                if i == v1[len(v1)+1]:
                    v1 = v1 + 'ing'
    return ''


def default_positive_form():
    try:
        sbj = ['He',
               'She',
               'It',
               'I',
               'You',
               'We',
               'They']
        v1 = ['be',
              'beat',
              'become',
              'begin',
              'bend',
              'bet',
              'bid',
              'bite',
              'blow',
              'break',
              'bring',
              'build',
              'burn',
              'buy',
              'catch',
              'choose',
              'come',
              'cost',
              'cut',
              'dig',
              'dive',
              'do',
              'draw',
              'dream',
              'drive',
              'drink',
              'eat',
              'fall',
              'feel',
              'fight',
              'find',
              'fly',
              'forget',
              'forgive',
              'freeze',
              'get',
              'give',
              'go',
              'grow',
              'hang',
              'have',
              'hear',
              'hide',
              'hit',
              'hold',
              'hurt',
              'keep',
              'know',
              'lay',
              'lead',
              'leave',
              'lend',
              'let',
              'lie',
              'lose',
              'make',
              'mean',
              'meet',
              'pay',
              'put',
              'read',
              'ride',
              'ring',
              'rise',
              'run',
              'say',
              'see',
              'sell',
              'send',
              'show',
              'shut',
              'sing',
              'sit',
              'sleep',
              'speak',
              'spend',
              'stand',
              'swim',
              'take',
              'teach',
              'tear',
              'tell',
              'think',
              'throw',
              'understand',
              'wake',
              'wear',
              'win',
              'write']
        sbj = random.choice(sbj)
        v1 = random.choice(v1)
        verb_debug = v1_debug(v1, sbj)
        sen = ''
        if sbj == 'I':
            sen = sbj + 'am' + verb_debug
        elif sbj == 'He' or 'She' or 'It':
            sen = sbj + 'is' + verb_debug
        elif sbj == 'You' or 'We' or 'They':
            sen = sbj + 'are' + verb_debug
        print(f'{sen}')
    except NameError:
        print('this is bullshit')
    return

default_positive_form()
```

> this is python 3.8

Comment: Note that part of a good [mre] is that it be *minimal* -- that it be the shortest possible code that creates the same problem. Surely there's no need to include the full word lists. Heck, you could probably eliminate the use of random choice altogether and still be able to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: What do you think `if v1 != str and subject != str` does? Hint: It's not checking whether those variables _are_ strings; it tests whether they _point to the `str` type constant_.

Comment: ...anyhow, this is part of why just calling `sys.exit()` without printing any debugging beforehand is a general bad idea; it doesn't give you any clues about _why_ your program exited. Better to raise an exception when you have an error.

Answer (score 0):

`sen` will only consist of an empty string if none of the conditions of your `if/elif/elif` blocks are met. Change the print line to

```
print(f"sen is: {sen}")
```

But that's not the real problem. `obj != str` does not check if `obj` is a string, it checks to see if the object is pointing to the type constant `str` (Thanks Charles Duffy for the comment). Instead, use the builtin function [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) like so:

```
if not isinstance(v1, str) and not isinstance(subject, str):
    print("Variables are the wrong type!")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Clearly not the problem. Still happens if an`else` clause is added containing `sen = "Don't know how to handle subject: " + sbj`; see https://ideone.com/T6Z3va

Comment: Rather, the `sys.exit()` after the incorrect type check is the problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I just updated my answer. On second thought, maybe I'll change it altogether.